# Can I install Ubuntu on MID TAB WMS8153?

Tags: installation, tablet, ubuntu-touch

Following are the hardware details:

**Model:** Wondermedia WM8650
**Android version:** 2.2
**Kernel version:** 2.6.32.9-default
**Build number:** generic-eng 2.2 froyo ver1.5.8-20120331.113758

- M788 - DDR2256
- 4G SS125040XC
- Green LED power ON
- wms8153_7inch_2g

Please let me know the best way to install Ubuntu on my tablet.

Answer (score 0):

You will find a list of supported ARM and other tablets [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/TabletList). Unfortunately, it's quite short, so I guess the answer is no.

However, there is an ARM version of Ubuntu, and you could try to install it following [these](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/OmapDesktopInstall) instructions.